# Why does changing a source file's name affect the size of its compressed version?

Tags: compression, 7-zip, tar

Using `gzip` on CentOS 7, I just compressed a source file into a `.gz` file, then I found I got the source file's name wrong, so I changed the source file's name and compressed it again, and interestingly the new `.gz` file has a slightly different size than the old one.

I tested this again using `7zip` on Windows 10 and `pigz` on AlmaLinux 8, and the same thing always occurs. Here's the terminal output from AlmaLinux 8:

```
[user@localhost compress-test]$ ll
total 402152
-rwxrwx---. 1 user user 411801616 Jan 31 17:04 wps-office-11.1.0.11664-1.x86_64.rpm
[user@localhost compress-test]$ 
[user@localhost compress-test]$ cp wps-office-11.1.0.11664-1.x86_64.rpm wps.rpm 
[user@localhost compress-test]$ 
[user@localhost compress-test]$ ll
total 804304
-rwxrwx---. 1 user user 411801616 Jan 31 17:04 wps-office-11.1.0.11664-1.x86_64.rpm
-rwxrwx---. 1 user user 411801616 Jan 31 17:05 wps.rpm
[user@localhost compress-test]$ 
[user@localhost compress-test]$ pigz -k wps*
[user@localhost compress-test]$ 
[user@localhost compress-test]$ ll
total 1605744
-rwxrwx---. 1 user user 411801616 Jan 31 17:04 wps-office-11.1.0.11664-1.x86_64.rpm
-rwxrwx---. 1 user user 410333369 Jan 31 17:04 wps-office-11.1.0.11664-1.x86_64.rpm.gz
-rwxrwx---. 1 user user 411801616 Jan 31 17:05 wps.rpm
-rwxrwx---. 1 user user 410333340 Jan 31 17:05 wps.rpm.gz
[user@localhost compress-test]$ 
[user@localhost compress-test]$ cksum *.rpm
3981101647 411801616 wps-office-11.1.0.11664-1.x86_64.rpm
3981101647 411801616 wps.rpm
[user@localhost compress-test]$
```

The `cksum` results proves that `wps-office-11.1.0.11664-1.x86_64.rpm` and `wps.rpm` are indeed identical, and `pigz -k wps*` guarantees both files were compressed with the same compression parameters. Yet the two resulting `.gz` files are slightly different in size.

This isn't causing me any issues. I am just curious why this happens. I don't know much about compression, is it because a file's name is a kind of "metadata" used by the compression program to create the compressed file's content?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the original filename is being encoded in the output.

The size difference is 29 bytes and that would correspond with the plain text of `-office-11.1.0.11664-1.x86_64` which is 29 characters by my count.

It is probably storing the filename along with a checksum of the file. The checksum will be the same but the filenames differ by those 29 bytes.

Comment: Thanks, if I rename the file and keep the names the same length, then the resulting compressed files would also be of the same size (however the checksums of the compressed files would be different).

Answer (score 1):

Compression software (in the vast majority of cases) stores a small header in the archive file that holds information about each file/folder contained in the compressed archive. That information typically has the original filename, the files attributes/metadata (size, date/time, permisions, etc) and a checksum.
Because you changed the length of the filename this header varied in size as well.
If you had renamed the file, but kept the filename the same length the resulting archive would have been the same size, but still wouldn't have had the same exact content.
Actually: Not changing anything, but doing a second archive a few minutes later may already result in a slightly different archive because of date/time fields in the header having changed in the time between making 2 archives.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed if the copied files' names are of the same length, then the compressed files would also have the same size. I copied `wps.rpm` as `wps123.rpm` and `wps456.rpm`, and the compressed `wps123.rpm.gz` and `wps456.rpm.gz` have the same size (but different checksums). However, compressing the same file at different times doesn't seem to affect the checksums or the file size.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you meant by saying "but still wouldn't have had the same exact content"? Like, if I renamed `wps.rpm` to `spw.rpm`, then `wps.rpm.gz` and `spw.rpm.gz` should be the same size, and the RPMs should also be the exact same RPM package (minus the names), right? Or, are two files considered "exactly the same", only when its binary content AND the file names are the same? Thanks!

Comment: @NoobAdmin It depends on the archive format (zip, 7z, rar, gz, tar.gz,) if a 2nd archiving of the same source-file at a later time will result in exactly (binary content identical) the same archive files. Some formats store last-access-time and/or last-modfication-time of the orignal in the header and those fields may have changed between making the 2 archives.

Comment: Alright I'll look into these formats later. So far the .gz format doesn't seem to take time into account. Thanks!